# Using React-router with Jekyll

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, jekyll, vue-router, react-router-v4

So i had this thought about making a **Jekyll SPA** blog
and somehow make use of something like **React.js** / **React Router** or **Vue.js** / **Vue Router** to achieve that SPA routing feel.

Is it possible to achieve this, and if so where would i import and use the router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with Jekyll (I assume that you want to show in `router-view` component pages generated by Jekyll).

A better way would be creating a blog entirely in Vue (or React). When you push changes to Github repository, you should have configured Travis that will build the whole project and push to `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: Thanks! 
That's a really neat idea !

Comment: There is Gatsby now :)